# Emacs remote shell

Tags: shell, emacs

I tend to run my shell in emacs, but when I use it to ssh into another computer this breaks tab-completion.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Were you expecting filename completion on a path that is machine specific (e.g. local disk)?  Commands in general?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
M-x cd /hostname:/current/path/in/the/shell
```

That should set up ange-ftp (or tramp), and then TAB completion for paths should work properly for that shell - until you log into a different machine.

You could set up a comint process filter to recognize when you type `ssh` to do that for you automatically, but that's difficult to get right as it should revert when you exit the `ssh` session, but not be tricked by other uses of `exit`.

For an automated solution, I'd suggest augmenting [the approach I personally use](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/08/emacs-tip-25-shell-dirtrack-by-prompt.html) to keep Emacs synchronized with the current working directory of the shell buffer.  Just add an an extra bit of information with the hostname, and use that to set the hostname and path like shown above.

Answer (score 2):

in another thread, someone mentioned eshell which I've never used but I tried it with SSH and all sorts of nice integration is happening. Time to learn eshell.

Answer (score 1):

You could try M-x ansi-term to host your shell if your getting unexpected behavior with key mappings. Having said that I couldn't re-produce the problem your describing on your set-up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I think and solved it by editing my ~/.bash_login on the remove machine and append

```
export TERM=xterm
```

I use OS X and had problems when connecting to a Linux (Debian Lenny)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a little function to open a shell on a remote host. The `cd` call before `shell`  gets the tab completion working.

This may be different than you want, since it opens a new shell instead of ssh'ing in a local shell. Beyond that, you could look into hacking emacs [Directory Tracking](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Directory-Tracking.html) (or see who else has).

```
(defun remote-shell (&optional host)
  "Open a remote shell to a host."
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((host (if host host (read-string "Host: "))))
      (cd (concat "/scp:" host ":"))
      (shell (concat "*" host "*")))))

(defun myserver-shell () (interactive) (remote-shell "myserver"))
```

Answer (score 0):

M-x shell invoked in buffer A will switch to a shell buffer B; usually *shell*.  Unsurprisingly it creates B if necessary.  A prefix arg will cause it to ask for the name of B.  If A is viewing something on a remote host then the shell will be run on the remote host.  But only if it can't find an existing B.  At that point file name completion will work.

There are some notes about how to tinker with this in the emacs wiki.  See for example the function my-shell in [this section](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode#toc3), which will extend the default name for B so remote files get remote shells.  I do that same thing by [advising the shell function](https://gist.github.com/bhyde/66acf3c339a80b306d10).

The filename auto completion will work fine.  Command autocomplete?  Less so.  For me it blocks emacs and then doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I use **dired** to access the remote machine and open a shell there.

Here is the function I use, taken and modified from [Tikhon Jelviss' emacs configuration](http://www.quora.com/What-does-Tikhon-Jelviss-Emacs-setup-look-like):

```
(defun anr-shell (buffer)
  "Opens a new shell buffer where the given buffer is located."
  (interactive "sBuffer: ")
  (pop-to-buffer (concat "*" buffer "*"))
  (unless (eq major-mode 'shell-mode)
    (dired buffer)
    (shell buffer)
    (sleep-for 0 200)
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (comint-simple-send (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) 
                        (concat "export PS1=\"\033[33m" buffer "\033[0m:\033[35m\\W\033[0m>\""))))
```

Example:

```
(anr-shell "/vagrant@localhost#2222:/vagrant/")
```