# Can I get GNU Emacs to TAB complete filenames after using ssh in the *shell* buffer?

Tags: shell, emacs, ssh

I am using GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (i486-pc-linux-gnu).

What I want is conceptually simple, [TAB] indicates that I press the
TAB key.

M-x shell

erik@furby:~$ ls
bin  Desktop  Documents  Dropbox  R.tools

erik@furby:~$ cd Drop[TAB]

and tab completion works fine (i.e., Dropbox is completed)

However, as soon as I ssh, this no longer works.

ssh erik@remote.edu
Terminal = dumb
erik@remote:~> ls
bin private

erik@remote:~> cd priv[TAB]

and the minibuffer displays 
"No completions of priv"

I've found others with the same problems, but
could not discern the solution.

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/56103-tab-completion-problem-ssh-shell-through-emacs.html

[Emacs remote shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134149)

Comment: possible duplicate of [emacs Remote Shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134149/emacs-remote-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after I posted the question, I stumbled on [**dirtrack-mode**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellDirtrackByPrompt) , which appears to have a solution, although not entirely trivial.  It uses dirtrack-mode, and the author says:

"It took me a long time to figure out how to get tab-completion working in shell-mode when I was ssh’d into another computer."

It's been annoying me for years; I'm glad I'm not the only one!

Comment: Unfortunately your link died. [Is this the right one](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/08/emacs-tip-25-shell-dirtrack-by-prompt.html)? In the meantime, I replaced it with the emacswiki article on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer to a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858475/89989) worked for me:

1. `C-x C-f /user@host:~` (open a directory on the remote server in dired mode)
2. `M-x shell` in the dired buffer

Answer (score 0):

It works with `eshell` if you instead of doing `ssh user@host` you do `cd /ssh:user@host:` however it doesn't seem to work with `shell`.